# Is there a classification of 2-nilpotent groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory

A divisible abelian group is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbf Q$ and Prüfer groups, where as an abelian group of bounded exponent is isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups.

> **Question 1.** Is there a classification of divisible 2-nilpotent groups?
>
> **Question 2.** Is there a classification of 2-nilpotent groups of bounded exponent?

Comment: Essentially, the answer is NO in both cases. For (2) 2-nilpotent groups of exponent (dividing) $p$, for prime $p\ge 3$, are the same (via Malcev-Lazard correspondence) as 2-nilpotent Lie algebras over the field $\mathbf{F}_p=\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$. There is no reasonable classification of such Lie algebras, except in small dimension (there is not even a classification in the algebraically closed case, which is simpler in principle). For (1), and just restricting to the torsion-free case, this is the same discussion replacing $\mathbf{F}_p$ with $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Also an example: mod out the Heisenberg group over $\mathbf{Q}$ by a cyclic subgroup of its center: one gets a divisible nilpotent group that is not direct product of a torsion group and a torsion-free group.